# Why is server is waiting with second request untill first is fisnished

Tags: apache2, connections, time-wait

Not sure what it is, but everytime I try to run one http request from browser, second must wait for first to fisnish. Is it server side configuration/seciurirty?

For example, I have 2 files `long.php` and `short.php`. After making request to `long.php` one I totally cannot open `short.php`. After `long.php` is finished, `short.php` is then loaded.

Not sure what it is related to. It does not happen for short scripts... only big ones. Maybe one IP user can open one connection to database etc?

*EDIT*:
Great example of how to "reproduce" this is to install XAMPP, start import of database on one browser. During that time, I cannot open another phpMyAdmin tab and work. Have to open different browser and then can work normally.

Firefox Tab 1: Imporing database with phpmyadmin
Firefox Tab 2: Opening phpmyadmin waits untill Tab 1 finishes
Chrome Tab 1: Works without problems or delays.

Comment: You need to explain your PHP setup: are you using modphp, php-fpm, etc? I can already tell you that it's likely a worker issue: there is only one process/thread available. How to configure this properly depends on what PHP infrastructure you have.

Comment: @Halfgaar Sorry for late response, couldn't earlier.
Don't think its worker number issue, It happens on alot of serwers, with ngix etc.
It more lookls like one browser = one connection. Cause if I open same site in other browser while first is "working/waiting" other one works fine.

Comment: @Halfgaar Added example I can reproduce everytime.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with two `curl` commands? One like `time curl --head -X GET https://www.yourserver.net/slow.php` and then in other window `time curl --head -X GET https://www.yourserver.net/fast.php`. You can include the output in your question.